# How to re-use a modal for delete confirmation?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that I want to re-use for my delete confirmations.

So basically without a delete confirmation I would have a button, that when pressed, would make a POST (or DELETE) request to something like:

```
example.com/post/1231
```

I want to somehow re-use a modal for this type of operation, any tips on how to do this?

When someone clicks the button:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirmModal">Delete</a>
```

How can I pass the information to the modal to make a POST/DELETE request when the #deleteConfirm button is clicked?

I have a template of a modal here:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteLabel">Deleting a Notification</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You have selected to delete this notification.</p>
                <p>
                    If this was the action that you wanted to do,
                    please confirm your choice, or cancel and return
                    to the page.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteConfirm">Delete Notification</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS API instead of data attributes:

```
$('#deleteConfirmModal').modal('show');
```

And then store request type somewhere for example in data:

```
$('#deleteConfirmModal').data('request_type', 'DELETE');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/post/1" data-request-type="delete" class="confirm-action">Delete</a>
        <a href="/post/1" data-request-type="update" class="confirm-action">Update</a>
  <div id="log"></div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteLabel">Deleting a Notification</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p>You have selected to delete this notification.</p>
      <p>
       If this was the action that you wanted to do,
       please confirm your choice, or cancel and return
       to the page.
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteConfirm">Delete Notification</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        $('a.confirm-action').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var modal = $('#deleteConfirmModal');
   modal.data('url', $(this).attr('href'));
   modal.data('request_type', $(this).data('request-type'));
            modal.modal('show');
        });
  
  $('#deleteConfirm').click(function () {
   var modal = $('#deleteConfirmModal');
   var url = modal.data('url');
   var request_type = modal.data('request_type');
   $('#log').append('Sent ' + request_type + ' to ' + url + '<br>');
   modal.modal('hide');
  });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain a little more, where I am storing the URL to POST to?